# RMarkdown and shiny as an html page

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to merge `Shiny` and `RMarkdown`, two amazing packages.
Generally i work with RMarkdown in RStudio, creating some `htlm`s pages, that I can send to other people whom simply need to see some desired results/analysis, without any idea of what `R` is and so on.

I read this  [great source](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html), but the result giveth is a `.rmd` file that I cannot send to other user to read it without `R` (and they are not going to learn it).

When I am in RStudio I choose this:

[image]

The option says that I'm creating an `html` file, but I can only find the `.rmd` result (for this question, I'm using the example given by RStudio automatically).
I've noticed also this output in R Markdown console:

> Output created:
>
> C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/.../file474396077b6.html

But, opening this file, the shiny features are not shown.

Is there a way to create an `html` like a "classical" `rmarkdown` output to send to other users, whitout hosting it on a server, or give R to the other users?

Comment: yes and no. No, because shiny only works in R. Yes because you have other ways of working interactively. But nothing compares to `shiny`'s power. Therefore it basically depends on what you want to achieve. Try narrowing down your question a bit, then we can get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I was simply looking around to see generally if I can use `shiny` as another tool of data viz and analysis, I've not got any concrete example to show. However we can start with the general example created in RStudio when you choose to make a `rmarkdown` with `shiny `object.

Comment: Both don't work in any other package. There is **no** replacement for `shiny`. There is only imperfect workarounds. Try defining what you need and what html standalone you want to create. Then come back here if you're there

Comment: @nihil Have you experimented all the options detailled here: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/2671/Combining-Shiny-R-Markdown.html?